# Exception when trying to initialize CrystalReports ReportDocument

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, .net-2.0

I have some kind of problem with Crystal Reports.
Whenever I try to initialize a ReportDocument or fill ReportViewer I got following exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: {"The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an
>   exception."}

This line of code produces the exception:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument repDoc = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
```

I've reinstalled Crystal Reports but with no results.
It is strange that it works fine on every other computer we have around.

What else can I do?

Comment: check that the report file isnt corrupted on the disk and that there are no GACed versions of the dlls that could cause problems. That it is limited to one system points to something hinkey about the system itself.

Comment: Looks like a references problem. Did you try removing the crystal reports references from the project and add them again? Make sure you add the same references as on the other machines, and that the version of the references match each other and also the installed version.

Comment: I've done that and I've checked version numbers, but to no avail.

Comment: Does this code run on a server?

Comment: No, it runs on development machine, well it was supposed to be publishing machine.

Answer (score 1):

Had this happen before, and the solution for me was that i had inadvertantly uninstalled the Crystal Reports Runtime.

You have a .net-2.0 tag, so try search your files for 'CRRedist2008_x86.msi' or CRRedist2005_x86.msi depending on which version of Visual Studio you're using

Or re-download:

- Visual Studio 2010 runtime: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824
- Visual Studio 2008 runtime: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27917
- Visual Studio 2005 runtime: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27942

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to the corrupted files of Crystal Report version 13-0-22 runtime engine. what i did to solve that issue was:

1. Uninstall CRforVS13_0_22
2. Uninstall CrRuntimeREngine13_0_22_64bit
3. Restart PC
4. Install CRFORVS13_0_22
5. Install CRRuntimeEngine13_0_22
6. Install CrRuntimeEngine13_0_24 (Upgraded the 13_0_22 to 13_0_24)
7. Restart PC
8. Opened the Solution in VS
9. Clean Solution
10. Build Solution

And it worked...